# get values of selected items in list with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i have one list in php page with follwoing script

```
<div id='demo' style="padding-left:20px">

<select name='lists[]' multiple='multiple' class='multiselect' >
<?php

$sql="select list_id,list_name from tbl_list";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
for($i=1;$i<=mysql_num_rows($result);$i++)
{
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
?>
<option  value='<?php echo $row['list_id']; ?>' title='<?php echo $row['list_name']; ?>'><?php echo $row['list_name']; ?></option>
 <?php
 }
 ?>           
  </select>
        </form>
      </div>
```

now after i select multiple rows in list box,  i want to get the values of selected rows with jquery.

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/val/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('select').val();
```

will return your selected values in the form x,y,z

Answer (score 1):

`$('select').val();`

to get the value of the select at that time

```
$('select').change(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

To get it every time it is changed.

Example for multiple selects on a page:
http://jsfiddle.net/Mxtey/

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

try `$("select").serialize();` and it probably give you exactly what you want
however there should be "form" first and after that you should use

`$("form").serialize();`